# Android: After building platform source, how to sign arbitrary APK with platform key?

Tags: android, android-ndk

As an experiment, I would like to use the platform key of my custom built Android platform to sign an arbitrary APK, that is built via the NDK. What is the process to go about doing this?

Comment: you also should delete META-INF folder in apk = zip -d my_application.apk META-INF/\*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you have your platform key/certificate pair (.pk8 + x509.pem).  Which can be found under build/target/product/security in the pulbic sdk.

You can use the SignApk.jar from the command line

> java -jar SignApk.jar
>   platform.x509.pem platform.pk8
>   Application.apk Application_signed.apk

Or to make automation easier, you can import the key/cert pair into your java keystore file, with the [keytool-importkeypair](https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair), and use an ant makefile or eclipse for signing.

> keytool-importkeypair -k
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore -p android
>   -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias platform

Comment: Getting an error while adb install <signedApp> :  "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl500742354.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/PLATFORM.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl500742354.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?]"

Answer (score 18):

The signapk.jar (all lowercase) file mentioned in [aprock' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257367/427545) can be found at `prebuilts/sdk/tools/lib/signapk.jar` (or `out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar`).

Below I will describe how to manage the keystore used by Eclipse and `ant release`.

---

The following command takes the key file **platform.pk8** and X509 certificate **platform.x509.pem** and outputs the decrypted key material in *tmp.p12*. The name **platformkey** is used to

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -nocrypt -in platform.pk8 | \
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in platform.x509.pem -inkey /dev/stdin \
    -name platformkey -password pass: -out tmp.p12
```

Eclipse and `ant debug` use the keystore at **~/.android/debug.keystore** which is locked with the password `android`. (You can also specify an other keystore file if you want to, e.g. `~/.android/mykeys.keystore`.) The next command stores the key material from *tmp.p12* in the keystore (without a password for the keys, if you want one, edit `-srcstorepass ''` below):

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass android -srckeystore tmp.p12 \
    -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass '' -destkeystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

At this point, you can delete the *tmp.p12* file because it is no longer needed.

In order to check what is in your keystore, you can run the next `keytool` command (the output it shown on the line thereafter):

```
$ keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
...
platformkey, Nov 23, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 12:34:56:(stripped):AB:CD:EF
```

When you no longer need the key, it can be removed with:

```
keytool -delete -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias platformkey
```

In your `local.properties` file, put (if you omit the `key.*.password` options, you have to enter it every time you sign the APK):

```
key.store=${user.home}/.android/debug.keystore
key.alias=platformkey
key.store.password=android
key.alias.password=
```

Now you can run `ant release` to sign your APK using the platform key you stored in a keystore.