# How can I access vehicle properties which have signature permission? Is it possible to root Android automotive OS?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-permissions, android-source, android-automotive

I need to access [VHAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds) properties like [ABS_ACTIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds#ABS_ACTIVE), [ENGINE_RPM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds#ENGINE_RPM), etc which are restricted with signature permissions. The third-party app access to VHAL is restricted with permissions. I will get OEM signature permission in the production build, but for testing, I need to sign my app with an AOSP certificate or I have to move my app into the system folder.

1. Where can I find those certificates?
2. How can I sign my app with those certificates?

Answer (score 1):

- Build your own custom system image https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/avd
- Include your apk in the system image as part of the build (& you will need to pre-grant access to your apk (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist)

The system images that are published by Google/Volvo/Polestar are user/release-keys and hence you won't be to get those platform keys for it.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can sign your app with the default platform key that comes with android.
[The Android tree includes test-keys](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds#release-keys)

Comment: I tried signing as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257367/7094064). It is working in Android mobile AVD, but not in AVD running on the automotive OS.