# Making an app in the Android Source compile into system/app instead of data/app?

Tags: android, android-source, rom

I'm compiling an Android ROM from source, and I have several apps that compile, but into data/app on the phone. They're uninstallable through the phone settings. I want them to be impossible to uninstall from the phone, and to compile into system/app instead of data/app.

Any advice?

edit:typo

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience compiling apps with a ROM, but I do know you need to sign the apps with the system signature to make them system apps. Does the following link do the trick? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature

Comment: Giving it a shot. I added it to the <application /> tag, hope that's the right place.

Edit: OOPS adding it to the <maifest /> tag and retrying

Comment: You also need to sign the app with the right key, not just add that value to the manifest.

Comment: I'm trying to sign the app by setting LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := system in Android.mk for my app, but now it's not installing the app at all

Comment: I'm afraid make files are out of my expertise comfort zone. Someone else may be able to help you there.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := system/app
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

Comment: can you give a documentation for that? when I put that is mk file the app will not built at all

Comment: What does LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of mk file that you can use. In my case the application is then build into `system/app`:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := package_name
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

# Use the folloing include to make our test app
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: In android building all default application  goes into system/app what if i want to send them in data/app ?

Comment: please see my quetsion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984572/making-an-app-in-the-android-source-compile-into-data-app-instead-of-system-app

Answer (score 0):

With cm_10.2, I added my app into packages/apps and by default, mm built it into /data/app. I wanted it into system/app. It worked by adding this into Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
```

But I'm not sure if it's a clean way to proceed since I almost found nobody doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyTestApp

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libarity android-support-v4

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```