# How do I install an app into the data/app folder instead of the system/app folder in an AOSP build?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I put my application folder in

```
packages/apps  // inside AOSP source code
```

Now my application has following `Android.mk` in the same folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := package_name
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

# Use the folloing include to make our test app
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Now when I build my AOSP project, it also compiles my application and puts the APK file inside:

**out/target/product/$MY_PLATFORM/system/app**

But I want to put it in:

**out/target/product/$MY_PLATFORM/data/app**

How do I do this? What make file do I change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution by changing this thing in `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests
```

Comment: this puts the apps in /data/app (by creating a userdata.img partition) but the AOSP's behavior is to not include data partition in the final built image. So do you know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the android AOSP build system doesn't build anything into /data.  The idea of the /data partition is that it's user data, and that it will be shipped from the factory empty (and deleted entirely on a device reset).  If you want to install something into /data you do it after install using "adb install" or any other mechanism.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, in my case, I want to debug a system app. My plan was to root the device, remove the app from /system/, compile it locally with "mm" and then install it in /data/. This lets me do a compile-install-test cycle without having to rebuild the entire ROM or re-flash the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of some other system app. Copy your target app which need to be installed in `/data` in say `/system/usr/share`

```
   device/<your platform> /extras/usr/share/<target app>:system/usr/share/<target app name> \
```

write above rule in 
`device/platform/<platform specific mk >`

Now using some other system level app you can check whether your app is installed or not. If not installed install it via package manager by giving above path 
`system/usr/share/<target app name>`