# Install apps in data/app instead of default system/app when building android from source

Tags: android, android-source

When i build my android source code, my apps install as system apps in system/app. I do not want that. I want my apps to install as normal apps in data/app which also makes it easy for the user to uninstall the app

This answer did not help me,
[Install an app  into data/app instead of system/app in the Android Source compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984572/install-an-app-into-data-app-instead-of-system-app-in-the-android-source-compil)

Comment: People seem to get real upset about android-source questions because they don't understand them, have an upvote to even it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Andoid Source build makes the system.img.  This does not include the data partition so you cannot add apps to the data partition.  Apps that are built by the source go into either /system/app or /system/priv-app.