# Calling System.loadLibrary twice for the same shared library

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have the situation when two jar libraries use the same shared library.
In each library "the main interface" class loads the .so file with `System.loadLibrary`.
My question is: if the user decides to use these two jar libraries in one project, would the second call to `System.loadLibrary` for the same .so file cause any exception? Or is it "somehowe handled" by the system to prevent shared libraries from being loaded twice? Or maybe there is a "commonly known pattern" to handle such situations?

The jni wrappers are targeted to be used on android. I am the author of both wrapper libs so answering you can assume full control on java sources.

Comment: I have not tested it, but according to the [apidocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) it should not be a problem: "If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored."

Comment: Thanks, it seems to fully answer my question. Put it as answer not comment in order that I could accept it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [apidocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) it should not be a problem: "If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored."

Comment: to help future folks who might be searching for the word "Idempotent", there it is.

Answer (score 9):

I've found one very narrow use case when this will be a problem.

If you are running Android system app, with `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in manifest, either pre-installed to the device, or [signed with the platform certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature), and you are trying to call `System.loadLibrary` twice to load the same library (either by running the same app twice, or creating two separate system apps loading the same library), Android will reboot.

Invoking JNI method from this library, if it was not yet loaded, will not generate an exception when running inside `android.uid.system` process, as with normal Android app - it will reboot Android.

To prevent that, and find out if the library was already loaded, you can read file `/proc/self/maps` and search for your library name there. `ClassLoader` and reflection will not help here - they will show JNI methods as accessible even when the library is not yet loaded.

Note that you cannot do `if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/grep <library-name> /proc/self/maps").waitFor() == 0)` - system process is forbidden from launching any external commands by SELinux, you will have to read the file from the Java code.

Another quirk is that the library must be preinstalled to device to the `/system/lib` directory - if you bundle the library with your app, and install the app to device, library will end up in `/data/app/..../lib`, and when you will try lo load it from `/data` partition, well you already guessed - Android will reboot.

Comment: Actually a narrow scenario ;). But thanks for your contribution.