# How can give System permissions to my own app with ANDROID-X86-4.4-RC1?

Tags: android, events, permissions, certificate, inject

I have my android device running on AndroidX86 (ANDROID-X86-4.4-RC1).
I want to install on it, my own app with permission to inject events. After many research, I follow this step :

1. I add INJECT_EVENTS use-permission in my manifest. I also tried   to
   use :  android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" but i get this error : Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
2. Signed my app with the platform signature like here ([How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature))
3. Put my app into /system/priv-app using adb and superuser privileges. I also tried to put it in /system/app but it doesn't
       work anymore.

After this, I run my app and use adb shell ps to verify if my app is running as system ? And no, it doesn't and i still have permission denied when my app have to inject events. 
Is there any other way to get the permission?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out how to install an app in /system/priv-app to use system level permissions? Thank You.