# How to run service when force stop is clicked in android

Tags: android, service

I have stuck with an issue of running a service when force stop is clicked and when i restart my mobile the service should be invoked.I have followed some examples but i cant able to achieve the task.Can any one guide me to achieve the task.

**Required:**

```
1.Service should run when force stop has been clicked from settings
2.Service should run when mobile has been restarted.
```

**TestActivity.java**

package com.testsearching;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class));
    }
}
```

**ServiceTest.java**

```
package com.testsearching;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 2 * 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private Timer mTimer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Log", "Running");

        }
    };

    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.techtrainner");
        intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**ReceiverCall.java**

```
    package com.testsearching;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.i("Service Stops", "Ohhhhhhh");
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class));;
            Toast.makeText(context, "My start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testsearching"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.testsearching.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".ServiceTest" >
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.testsearching.ServiceTest" />
    </intent-filter>

        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="ReceiverCall"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.techtrainner" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have u tried return START_STICKY; in onStartCommand?

Comment: When user does force stop, means he does not want to run this application (any component). _he is not interested anymore_, and this is rights of user. SO android does not gives a way to keep running your service, even after forced close your app.

Comment: @Spurdow:where it should be done.. can u give me an example

Comment: @PankajKumar:In some of application Force stop has been disabled can it be done. How about restar service when mobile booted.. can it be done

Comment: @Giridharan on boot you have implemented the correct code.

Comment: @PankajKumar:but i didnt get response ya

Comment: Add dot to receiver name. `android:name=".ReceiverCall"` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

*In theory*, this is not possible; according to the Android security model.

As Panaj Kumar points out in the comments:

> When user does force stop, means he does not want to run this
>   application (any component). *he is not interested anymore*, and this
>   is rights of user. SO android does not gives a way to keep running
>   your service, even after forced close your app.

Android will prevent the app from restarting using the `START_STICKY` flag, and will disable the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver. The system will also disable all Alarms that have been set for this app.

Before the system will allow the app to run again, the user must run an `Activity` of the app themselves.

---

That said, it seems that certain apps are still able to break the rules in this way. This should be considered incorrect and would be taking advantage of a security hole, however it shows that it is still possible, even on KitKat.

The Discovery Insure driving app seems to be able to restart itself when it has been force stopped, and will restart on boot:

- [Discovery Insure Driving Challenge on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.discovery.insure.drivingapp&hl=en)

However, this functionality should not be relied on - hopefully this security flaw will be fixed in future system updates.

Comment: Le Mesurie: In some of the application force stop has been disabled .. Can i know how it can be achieved

Comment: @Giridharan AFAIK this is possible for System apps only, which means most of us will not be able to do this. Read more about that on this question: [How to sign Android app with system signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

Comment: @jaimin Google does not review apps the way Apple reviews apps. It is possible to submit an app like this. If Google detects malware, or has an app reported to them, then they will remove it. There is a difference between what Google allows on the app store, and what the security model of the Android system allows.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier:suppose if am going to publish on my internal sever. not publishing in Google play can we able to achieve of force stop

Comment: It does not matter where you publish it. But if you have ROOT on the device, you can install to the system folder. There's some more info on that [over here...](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Write this on in your **OnCreate** of the main launching activity

```
if(!isMyServiceRunning(ServiceClass.class))
    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),ServiceClass.class));
```

here is the running service check function

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and Create your service with this architecture.Observe the return **START_STICKY**

```
public class ServiceClass extends IntentService {
    public ServiceClass()
    {
        super("null");
    }
    public Context context;
    public Intent intent;
    public Date currentTime;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onHandleIntent(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intnt) {

        currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        this.intent = intnt;
        Log.d("ServiceClass","Service class running "+ currentTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are messing with factory methods of service, As per the documentation by using IntentService we cannot override onStartCommand the OS handles it by its own, the only method which do the work for intent service is onHandleIntent

Comment: correct your answer or simply delete it to prevent it from downvotes.

Comment: I agree that its a bad practice to override onStartCommand for IntentService  because it haults the onHandleIntent and therefore it has to be handled manually which is done above. But as  suggested by Richard Le Mesurier, let the user quit the service in first place.