# How to app use system permission on lollipop

Tags: android, permissions, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to use the permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER and it is need system or signature, I searched a lot and seems the apk in /system/priv-app may have the permission, but I failed on my Nexus 4 5.0.2.

I put the apk to /system/priv-app, but the logcat shows that

Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package xxxx

Is there something wrong I did? Or is there any other ways to get the permission?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation on `android:protectionLevel` in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

Only permissions with a protection level of signatureOrSystem will be assigned upon install if the app is included in the `/system/priv-app` folder. `android.permission.DEVICE_POWER` is not one of these. Refer to the manifest definition [in the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.2_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml):

Here is the excerpt:

```
   <!-- Allows low-level access to power management.
   <p>Not for use by third-party applications. -->
    <permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
        android:label="@string/permlab_devicePower"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_devicePower"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Hence the app needs to be [signed with the platform key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651653/3063884) of the ROM/system/AOSP-build in order to attain this permission.

Answer (score 0):

To get this permission, the application must be signed with the key which used to sign the platform. This may be different for manufacturers. So its practically not possible to get these permissions granted to a user application.

Following are some of the permissions that may NOT be granted to the user application:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER
android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER
android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET
android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN
android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD
android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER
android.permission.BRICK
android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS
android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH
android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED
android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE
android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA
android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES
android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES
android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES
android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC
android.permission.FACTORY_TEST
android.permission.FORCE_BACK
android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH
android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST
android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS
android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW
android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS
android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR
android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER
android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE
android.permission.REBOOT
android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER
android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION
android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS
android.permission.SET_TIME
android.permission.STATUS_BAR
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS
android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. Permissions with a protection level of `signatureOrSystem` will be assigned upon install if the app is included in the `/system/priv-app` folder. Only for permissions with `signature` protection level require application signing in order to be granted.

Answer (score 0):

clean your project it will be fine like this :

project -> Clean

May this will work for you

[How can i gain android.permission.DEVICE_POWER](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=694037)