# how to publish an apk that is signed with system signature?

Tags: android, publishing

I successfully created my android app that uses INJECT_EVENTS permission which is signed with the system signature using platform.pk8 & platform.x509.pem (key/certificate) ... with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

but unfortunately the two links in the 1st point are dead.Is there any other alternative to them ??

since,now I have an aligned apk,can I put on the play store without creating a keystore which we create when we export a signed application project `right click on project >android tools >Export signed application project` and also other things like creating an alias,password,my name,orgranization name & all that stuff!!
please help me with this!!!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Since this will only work with your custom ROM, what is the point of putting it on the Play Store?

Comment: Is there any other way to publish it?

Comment: Bundle it in with your custom ROM.

Comment: Since I am new to android, I am not so much familiar with Custom ROM Stuff,can you please help me with it by providing some sort of links or anything else.

Comment: "I am new to android" -- then please explain how you were able to write an "android app that uses INJECT_EVENTS permission which is signed with the system signature using platform.pk8 & platform.x509.pem". After all, you created the system signature files when you created your custom ROM, so you are already know "Custom ROM Stuff".

Comment: even though I,somehow managed to write an android app which is signed with System signature,I'm not sure what I have done in the background like creating "System signature files" & what are those?