# Android - Is there a way to get platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem the rom signed with?

Tags: android, x509certificate, platform

I was just curious if there is a way to get ***platform.pk8*** and ***platform.x509.pem*** which are used to sign the rom inside the Android device.

My aim is no more than developing system applications for testing and using my self-owned devices on my desired purpose.

---

*For those who are not familiar with creating system apks:* [signing an apk with system signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)  [WITHOUT ROOTING]

Comment: have you found any wayout with this.

Comment: I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 4):

No.

At least, not if the person building the ROM knows what they're doing.

From [the docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds.html#certificates-keys) (emphasis mine):

> Each key comes in two files: the certificate, which has the extension
>   .x509.pem, and the private key, which has the extension .pk8. **The
>   private key should be kept secret** and is needed to sign a package. The
>   key may itself be protected by a password. The certificate, in
>   contrast, contains only the public half of the key, so it can be
>   distributed widely. It is used to verify a package has been signed by
>   the corresponding private key.

If your device has an unlockable boot loader, you could build and flash your own ROM, using a key pair that you created yourself. That way, you'll have the platform private key to use for your system app.