# How to keep running an IntentService even when Home button is pressed

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I'm stuck with a strange problem, when I minimize my app (press home button) my `IntentService` stops. There is a while loop in the `IntentService`, it runs fine in the `IntentService` till app is running in foreground.

`IntentService` class is as follows:

```
public class MainService extends IntentService {

    public MainService() {
        super("MainService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();

            while (true) {
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And called it from my `Activity` class as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void mainButtonClick(View view) {
        Intent intentX = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
        this.startService(intentX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your logs? This is not problem with `IntentService` it is problem that you don't have permission to change volume after you left the app. It should crashing with:

> W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another
>   application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

You need to be system application to use this permission so this is not possible on regular Android devices.

Comment: Yes exactly same thing is there.

Comment: So only way is to root the device?

Comment: @KhurshidAbbas unfortunately it is not so simple, probably the only way is to build Android from source for your device, you can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)