# How to sign APK using Android Studio with system keys

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm able to sign the apk with system keys and pushing it to /system/priv apk works fine but is there any way that i can assign these keys to Android Studio rather than redoing the signing and pushing every time into /system/priv? Please suggest it will save a lot of time and strain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature