# Root privileges for an android application (Complete app. Not just few commands)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, root, su

### Question :

How to execute one complete app with root previleges (not just few commands)?

---

### Scenario :

I am working on a rooted android device.

In an android app, I need to play the H.264 stream received through `eth0`. **I need root privileges to open (raw open) `eth0`.**

The corresponding code is in JNI. **Since there are a lot of buffers that need to be exchanged between JNI code and Java code, the executable way(`Process.exec(su)`) is very inconvenient.**

---

### Ideal solution:

The JNI code is executed in the same process context as of the Java code. Therefore, granting root privileges to my android process should solve my problem. But I am not sure how to do that.

---

### I tried :

1. Making the application as `system app/priv-app`. I thought this will give the app root access. But that did not happen.

Comment: in your manifest you should have this (btw what version/s are you using ?)<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your application from **/system/app** to **/system/priv-app**.

Applications in /system/priv-app will have system level access.

/system is read-only without root so it prevents uninstalling applications from /system/app and /system/priv-app. Applications that are critical are put there so that they can't be uninstalled.

/system/priv-app allows apps installed there to use signatureOrSystem and other privileged permissions.

Comment: Thank you. But I still face the same issue. "Operation not permitted" After moving to priv-app, should I request for system permissions by declaring something in XML?

Comment: Add the below line in manifest
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" and sign the app using platform certificate.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature

Comment: Added that. But still the issue remains

Comment: Any progress with that?

Comment: @shlatchz No. Finally I am using socket IO between JNI and java.

Comment: @mk.. I also ended up using a socket between C++ code that runs as root and my Java app.