# Permission is not a changeable permission type

Tags: java, android, permissions

**Background:** I was trying out the new Tiles and TileService and decided to recreate the USB Tethering tile from [CyanogenMod.](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-13.0/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/tiles/UsbTetherTile.java) I used reflection to access Connectivity manager's methods.

**Problem:** One Such method is the `isTetheringSupported()` which causes `java.lang.SecurityException: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query user`

So I added the permissions to the manifest but every time I use `pm grant` it returns "Permission is not a changeable permission type"

According to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#2628) I should not get this error when signed with the debug key.

**Question:** How do I get those permissions?

Comment: and did you sign it?

Comment: @KhalilM yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE:***
Via *Xposed* it is possible to hook into the `PackageManger` and remove the below check and then do `pm grant...` to successfully grant whatever permission. If someone sees this and needs help to do so comment below I'll help you out.

**OLD ANSWER**
This code in the source

```
boolean isDevelopment =
            ((bp.protectionLevel&PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_FLAG_DEVELOPMENT) != 0);
```

doesn't check if your app is in development mode. It checks if the permission you are requesting has the `protectionLevel` attribute (set in manifest) set to `development`.
And the permission you are trying to get seems not to have any elements declared in the manifest that could pass this check:

```
if (!isNormal && !isDangerous && !isDevelopment) {
        throw new SecurityException("Permission " + bp.name
                + " is not a changeable permission type");
    }
```

Just stumbled upon this with another permission. Seems there's sadly no way to get it.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about the `development` protection level, but it turns out `CREATE_USERS` and `MANAGE_USERS` have protection level set to `signature` for which I should be able to use the `platform.x509.pem` and `platform.pk8` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security) to get the permissions. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

Comment: @Bhav yes those 2 permissions are not `development` protected so you can't access them through adb for instance as the check in the `if` stateament above will throw you the exception. If the protection level is `signature` you can only be granted that permission as in your attached post.