# READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission not granted

Tags: android

I'd like to grant android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission to my app, but even though it's a system app (in system-priv folder on a rooted device for tests) it's not granted.

ADB shows request for this permission, but it's not granted.

In the Manifest I have

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

When I try to check it in the runtime

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

the AS gives "Cannot resolve symbol 'READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE'" and the app won't compile.

Why READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is visible in the Manifest, but not visible in the java code (also missing in Manifest.class) ?

How can I grant this permission?

I tested it on rooted Android Oreo.

Edit: This answers a part of my question: [Permission is not a changeable permission type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174789/permission-is-not-a-changeable-permission-type)

The permission was granted on Lollipop, but not on Oreo.

But the question remains: Why READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is visible in the Manifest, but not visible in the java code (also missing in Manifest.class) ?

Comment: Is this a newly added permission and are you just installing the app with this permission over the existing system app or are you trying to push the app as a system app?

Comment: It's a clean install. I'm not installing over and existing app.

Comment: I don't know why there's no symbol for it, but you can use it's value instead: `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.getApplicationContext(), "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476817/android-api-29-permission-error-read-privileged-phone-state

Answer (score -1):

What I think might be happening is that Drobinsky did not call:

```
 String[] permissions = {"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"};
 int requestCode = 5;
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, requestCode);
```

prior to calling "ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(…"

In the activity you can also add a permissions notififcation handler which looks like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
 switch (requestCode) {
      case 5: //REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
 if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
      // Do what you want to do with the granted permission
```

Even though you've got the permission added in the manifest, the user must also grant this permission at runtime.  What happens is that a popup will occur asking the user to grant this permission, and if the user grants it, the "checkSelfPermission" method will then work correctly.  The popup block is automatic; i.e. no code needs to be added to the app. I think you can add a text message that displays the reason the permission is required. Certain permission requests need to be handled in this manner, whereas some permission requests are granted without user intervention required. I think the Android model is that if a request is deemed "dangerous" it requires the user give their permission to grant the app access to these so called dangerous privileges.