# Android API 29 Permission Error READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, permissions, android-10.0, imei, deviceid

I Have created Android App.
And Before Api 29 I was get Device IMEI Id.
Now Api 29 my methods return null.

```
TelephonyManager tm  = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            if (tm.getDeviceId() != null) {
               String imei=tm.getDeviceId();
            }
```

Android Documentation says that new version you must use new permission.
Permission is READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
but When I send it is not show to users for choose

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,   
                new String[]{"android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"},
                PERMISSIONS_CODE );
```

not showing.
How I pass this problem?

Comment: To use that permission you need to be "pre-installed" in the system area like `/system/priv-app`, then you can read IMEI if you have that permission in your Manifest and on the system area