# Updating WebView on AOSP Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-webview, android-source

I am working on a device based on AOSP Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).
I wanted to update standard Android webview to the latest version for using the latest JavaScript.
For this I replaced `external/chromium-webview/prebuilt/arm64/webview.apk` with the latest version.
Also in the `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` I changed the value of `config_webViewPackageName` from `com.android.webview` to `com.google.android.webview`.
But when I tried to launch some application that using webview (for example standard android browser) I got such error:

```
10-10 12:08:08.923 17802 17802 I WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 61.0.3163.98 (code 316309850)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory: error loading provider
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getChromiumProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:229)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:193)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:158)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.browser.BrowserSettings.syncSharedSettings(BrowserSettings.java:312)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.browser.BrowserSettings.setController(BrowserSettings.java:148)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.browser.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:235)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.createController(BrowserActivity.java:84)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.onCreate(BrowserActivity.java:73)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:742)
10-10 12:08:52.107 20530 20530 E WebViewFactory:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
```

Did somebody faced such issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we have found that the problem was because webmusic.apk was not signed with the system signature. That's why it was not properly installed.
Steps from the question [How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature) solved the issue.

Comment: Typo - webmusic.apk -> webview.apk