# How can xamarin send local notification to specific users or Show/hide?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using android local notification in my app, all work fine,
but my question is:

Is there any way to send notification to specific users or group, Or to show/hide the notification to/from specific users?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
  .SetAutoCancel(true)                    // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
  .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)  // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
  .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked")      // Set the title
  .SetNumber(count)                       // Display the count in the Content Info
  .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm))
  .SetDefaults(0)
  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notify)
  .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
  .SetContentText(String.Format("The button has been clicked {0} times.", count)); // the message to display.

// Finally, publish the notification:
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
```

Comment: ? Are you talking about remote notifications?

Comment: No, Local notification

Comment: Just do an `if` statement on your user/group  condition and do not build the notification in the first place ;-)

Comment: can give short code to explain

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to send notification to specific users or group, Or to show/hide the notification to/from specific users?

You will need to use [UserManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) to query Users, but to use that , your app need `MANAGE_USERS` permission, which has a protectionlevel of `signature|system`,which means that the application has to be signed with the platform key. You can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature/3651653#3651653).