# Android - where to get system signature what belongs to the image run on emulator

Tags: android, x509certificate, platform

I want to sign Android app with system signature?I know how to do it with this link.[How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

But I don't know how to get the **real** platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem.

I have tried the googlesource's system signature, but failed.
[android-8.1.0_r26/target/product/security](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-8.1.0_r26/target/product/security/)

The System Image the emulator loaded is `Google APIs intel x86 Atom System Image` as below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this for platforms in which you build the image (e.g. custom ROM or new device you are creating.)  The private signing keys used by commercial devices and/or Google are not available to the public.  That would be a major security hole as then any app could be signed like a system app and installed on end consumer devices.